# Filter and Display Entries Existing In Multiple Groups

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to learn PowerBI to become familiar with data analysis and visualizations. I'm working on a project with a friend where we've collected data for the price per 20 g of protein from various food sources (chicken legs, whole milk, quinoa, etc) in the Atlanta area from multiple grocery stores. This is simple enough and in our data table we've included a column for the type of protein (poultry, dairy, grains, etc) and PowerBI lets us easily filter our results with switches. However, we'd like to use DAX, New Measure, and/or New Column to display various diet types (pescatarian, vegetarian, allergic to nuts, etc). We originally tried to use Group By, but this didn't help us since it would assign a particular food source to one group. This is an issue since "whole milk" satisfies a pescatarian diet as well as a vegetarian diet. How can I go about creating filters that allow for entries to exist in multiple groups? At the moment I'm just working with the data from a single store though.

| type | source | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| poultry | chicken breast | 1.04 |
| dairy | whole milk | 1.01 |
| grain | quinao | 1.33 |

[image]

Comment: Please mark your old questions as solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "diets" table that will handle the many to one relationship between diets and sources.

[image: Diets Table]

Then create a relationship between "diets" and "food" using "source" from both tables as the related column.

[image: food and diets relationship]

Note that this does not follow a [star schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema), which is typically what you want. If one of your sources is missing from the diets table, it likely will not show in your final report.

[image]